# Scan to mail in an MFA Office365 environment

Tags: email, office365, multi-factor-authentication

We work in an Office365 environment with MFA active. We use 2 mailaccounts which are used for the following services:

- E-mail tasks
- Scan to mail

Since we switched to MFA it is not possible to use the services anymore.
For the e-mail tasks we need to hit "test connection" before it works and the scan to mail goes over the MX-record with port 25 active (unsecure)

Is there a way to set it up correctly or to disable the MFA settings for these 2 mail accounts?

As soon as we switch back to port 25 and the MX-record as SMTP server it's fine. But as soon as we use smtp.office365.com:587 it fails to authenticate.